# Perl HTTP Daemon Server- Reading POST JSON body

Tags: perl, http-daemon

I was using [HTTP::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Daemon-6.01/lib/HTTP/Daemon.pm) to create a http server for my API. With the help of following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14440365/1348550) and [doc](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Daemon-6.01/lib/HTTP/Daemon.pm), I was able to create a basic HTTP server.

However, my API should accepts JSON as a body in post request to the server. So, I need to read the JSON so that I can process it. I know, how to read url param `$r->uri->query_form();`

Is there a way to read POST JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
my $json = decode_json($r->content);
print Dumper $json;
```